# How to get all Jira statuses from a workflow of an issue by using rest API

Tags: rest, workflow, jira, status

I'm using Jira cloud. I want to get **all statuses** from a **workflow** of an issue by **using rest API**. I read Jira's rest api specification, searched google but no hope.

This [post](https://community.atlassian.com/t5/JIRA-questions/How-to-get-all-status-in-a-workflow/qaq-p/359172) look as same as my issue. However, the answer is not clear and it seems to be used for Jira server version.

Anyone please help! Thanks

---

Updated:

There are some solutions suggested by Atlassian's community.

1. Write a plugin with solution in above [post](https://community.atlassian.com/t5/JIRA-questions/How-to-get-all-status-in-a-workflow/qaq-p/359172).
2. Create a project that only has the workflow you're interested in, and then use the project API to retreive the statuses for that project (which will be limited to just that workflow).

Comment: I know that you can get available transitions like this: https://docs.atlassian.com/jira/REST/cloud/#api/2/issue-getTransitions not sure about all statuses

Comment: @Robert Thank you. I read that API, and it's not help in my use case. I found some solutions suggested by Atlassian's community. I will update above.